# Strange behaviour of "position: relative" when zooming. What's happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

**The Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/4WFrJ/

**My Problem**:
I can't wrap my head around the behaviour of this setup.
When I zoom in, the images tend to move faster, but when I zoom out, they don't move at all. Sometimes they just stop at 9.xxxxxx, even though I told them to move only by one pixel. Can you explain this?

My browser is Chrome.

**My Aim**: achieve a fluid motion with the images disappearing when out of bounds of the parent element, whatever the magnification percentage.

I am in search of the basic rules, that govern these strange processes, from which I hope to learn new things.

**The Code**:

*HTML*:

```
<div id = "presentation">
            <ul>
                <li class = "pres-item"> <img class = "pres-image" src = "../img/presentation/image1.jpg"> </li>
                <li class = "pres-item"> <img class = "pres-image" src = "../img/presentation/image2.jpg"> </li>
                <li class = "pres-item"> <img class = "pres-image" src = "../img/presentation/image3.jpg"> </li>
                <li class = "pres-item"> <img class = "pres-image" src = "../img/presentation/image4.jpg"> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

*CSS*:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#presentation {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#presentation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#presentation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pres-item {
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.pres-image {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

*JS* (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var presentation = $('#presentation');
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('intervaling');
        $('.pres-item').css('left', '+=1');
    }, 60);

});
```

**The Image**:

[image: The fixed position at 90% zoom]

**The Thanks**:

THANKS PEOPLE (in advance)

Comment: My browser is Google Chrome. Oh, it's doing that only in chrome, isn't it. That's even weirder than I thought.

Comment: They seem to move slower when zoomed out, but isn't that natural? If they move 4px per "tick," say, and you zoom out to 25%, then they will only appear to move at 1px per "tick," since 4 viewport pixels are being condensed into one screen pixel (or maybe we're just not seeing the same effect).

Comment: @DaggNabbit have posted an image: at 90% zoom the "left" property stays at that value. 9.99xxx. It doesn't increment at all. I have no idea why does it even obtain this kind of value, when I told it to increment only by 1 pixel. By the way, the strange thing is, it works just as I would expect in a browser like IE11!

Comment: @Rasteril, weird. It doesn't happen with this example, does it? http://jsfiddle.net/4WFrJ/1/

Comment: @DaggNabbit, yes, indeed it doesn't! jQuery, I thought I could trust you!

Comment: @Rasteril I know that feeling ;)

Comment: It'd actually interest me, what's happening here?

Comment: @DaggNabbit Your fiddle also differs from Rasteril's due to applying the transform to the enclosing div rather than the individual images. Does the same issue happen in Chrome when using `presentation.css('left', '+=1')` (with the presentation div's `left` property initially set to 0 pixels)?

Comment: Here's a jQuery version of the presentation div movement: http://jsfiddle.net/4WFrJ/3/. And here are two other ones to try, in case the issue is jQuery making assumptions about how the incremented value should be scaled/normalized in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/4WFrJ/2/, http://jsfiddle.net/4WFrJ/4/

Comment: @JAB it also needs `position` css property. I just checked it though, it seems fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    // too much code, but it explains..

    // do this in ur interval...

    var getCurrent_left = $('.pres-item').css('left');
    var newCurrent_left = getCurrent_left.split['px'];
    var newCurrent_left = parseInt(newCurrent_left[0]) + 1;
    var newCurrent_left = parseInt(newCurrent_left);

    $('.pres-item').css({"left", newCurrent_left});

    // you can use parseFloat(var, 2) for decimal


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My Problem:
>
> When I zoom in, the images tend to move faster, but when I zoom out, they don't move at all.

I'm not sure this is actually a problem. They appear to move slower when zoomed out because they travel fewer screen pixels for each viewport pixel.

> Sometimes they just stop at 9.xxxxxx, even though I told them to move only by one pixel. Can you explain this?

Apparently Chrome does not always return that CSS property as an integer. You can see the same effect in this code:

```
var presentation = document.getElementById('presentation');
var items = presentation.getElementsByClassName('pres-item');
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    [].forEach.call(items, function (x) {
        var lastLeft = getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue('left');        
        console.log(lastLeft);
        x.style.left = (parseFloat(lastLeft) + 1) + 'px';
    })
}, 60);
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem or not. You could easily avoid it by keeping track of the offset in a separate variable and incrementing it during your loop instead of computing it from the element's current style.

```
var presentation = $('#presentation');
var left = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ++left;
    $('.pres-item').css('left', left + 'px');
}, 60);
```